# ValueError: shapes (11,1) and (11,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to implement a Gaussian fit, i have a problem when i try to multiplie matrices as shown below. 
    why i got this error ?
   I print the result just to verify the multplication of the 2 matrices, on matlab when I do this I got matrice  with same size and the values are correct.

Any help please?

thanks

**the code**

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    spectre = pd.read_csv('spectre.txt')
    wl = pd.read_csv('longueur_d_onde.txt')
    spectre = spectre -8000
    A = wl.iloc[185:196,0]
    B = spectre.iloc[185:196, 0 ]
    #*******
    sigma = 2565/8192
    mu = A[192]
    A_ = np.transpose(np.matrix(A))
    Mu_ = np.transpose(np.zeros((1,len(A))))
    for i in range(len(A)):
        Mu_[i] = mu

    mu_ = A_-Mu_
    mu_t = np.transpose(mu_)
    for i in range (100):
        #Y = dat/dat[30]
        Y = np.matrix((B/B[192]))
        Yt = np.transpose(Y)
        N = np.exp(-np.power(mu_,2)//(2*sigma**2))
        print(N*np.power(mu_,2)) # when i print this i got the error.
```

**the error**

```
ValueError: shapes (11,1) and (11,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)
```

Comment: When using `np.matrix`, `*` means matrix multiplication, not element-wise.  Which do you want?  The use of `np.matrix` in new code is discouraged.  The regular arrays implement matrix multiplication with the `dot` method or `@` operator.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will try  this.

Comment: But how can I transpose an Array ?

Comment: transpose using A.T

Comment: You can transpose an ndarray, in your case Y, by using `Y.T` So `print(Y.T)` will print the transpose of Matrix Y. Please refrain from going off topic by asking multiple questions in one thread: ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Thank you B.Go. 
it's understood Psychotechnopath,

Comment: Transpose of a 1d array doesn't change anything.  Shape (n,) remains (n,).  But a (1,n) shape will transpose to (n,1).  But `dot` works with two (n,) shape arrays, returning the expected vector dot product (magnitude).

Comment: What's the purpose of that `for i...` loop?  You don't use the iteration variable `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your files I can't recreate your calculations, but I can make some suggestions.

```
A = wl.iloc[185:196,0]
B = spectre.iloc[185:196, 0 ]
```

`A` and `B` are now pandas Series.

```
sigma = 2565/8192
mu = A[192]
A_ = np.transpose(np.matrix(A))
```

`np.matrix(A)` produces a (1,11) shape `matrix`; `transpose` changes that to (11,1).  `A_ = A.to_numpy()` would create a (11,) `ndarray`.  `A_=np.reshape(A_, (11,1)` would make it 2d without the `np.matrix` overloading.

```
Mu_ = np.transpose(np.zeros((1,len(A))))
for i in range(len(A)):
    Mu_[i] = mu
```

`Mu_` is (11,1) `matrix` with `mu` in all slots.

```
mu_ = A_-Mu_
```

`mu_ = A_-mu` would have worked just as well.  No need to make `Mu_`.  `mu_` will have the same type and shape as `A_`.

```
mu_t = np.transpose(mu_)
```

No need to make `mu_t` (shape (1,11)).

I don't see what this loop is for.

```
for i in range (100):
    #Y = dat/dat[30]
    Y = np.matrix((B/B[192]))
    Yt = np.transpose(Y)
```

Again, `Y = (B/B[192]).to_numpy()` should be sufficient.  But `Y` isn't used below.

```
    N = np.exp(-np.power(mu_,2)//(2*sigma**2))
```

`N` has same type and shape as `mu_` (and `A_`)

```
    print(N*np.power(mu_,2)) # when i print this i got the error.
```

What is the purpose of this multiplication?  Is the result supposed to be a (11,1) element wise product, or (1,1) `dot` product?  Either way you don't need 2d `matrix`.

I think your code can be simplified to:

```
A_ = A.to_numpy()    # (11,) shape array
mu_ = A_ - mu
N = np.exp(-np.power(mu_,2)//(2*sigma**2))    # still (11,) shape
N*np.power(mu_,2)          # element-wise multiplication (11,) shape
N@np.power(mu_,2)          # dot product, scalar result
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the type of matrix-multiplication you expected. `N * np.power(mu_,2))` gives you the Hadamard product (Or element-wise matrix multiplication).

If you are looking for true matrix-matrix multiplication you'd want to use `N.dot(*np.power(mu_,2))` or `N @ np.power(mu_,2)`

Comment: thank you for your reply, 
I got this error when I try dot "TypeError: dot() takes at most 2 arguments (11 given)
"

Comment: same thing with @  "ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 11 is different from 1)"

Comment: For a matrix product a (11,1) array has to be paired with a (1,11).